# R - C++ code reproduction in Rcpp Math.Min issue

Tags: rcpp, levenshtein-distance

I am trying to reproduce a `C++` code that I found [here](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance#C.2B.2B) about the `LevenshteinDistance`.

More precisely, I am trying to reproduce the part starting by

```
static int LevenshteinDistance(string s, string t)
```

until

```
  return d[n, m];
 }
```

However, I am experiencing an error with `Math.Min(Math.Min(`. I am not sure what is the translation in `rcpp`. I tried with `min` but it doesn't seem to work. Any clue ?

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector LevenshteinDistance(NumericVector s, NumericVector t) {
    int n = s.size();
    int m = t.size();
    NumericMatrix d(n+1, m+1);

    if (n == 0)
    {
      return m;
    }

    if (m == 0){
      return n;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
      d(i, 0) = i;
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
      d(0, j) = j;

    for (int j = 1; j < m; j++)
      for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
        if (s(i - 1) == t(j - 1))
          d(i, j) = d(i - 1, j - 1);  //no operation
        else
            d(i, j) = min(
            d(i - 1, j) + 1,    //a deletion
            d(i, j - 1) + 1),   //an insertion
            d(i - 1, j - 1) + 1 //a substitution
        );
        return d(n, m);
  }
```

So with

```
d(i, j) = min(
```

I get this error message : `no matching function`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Three** issues really:

1. You have a typo

   ```
   d(i, j) = min(
   d(i - 1, j) + 1,    
   d(i, j - 1) + 1),  //typo here with )
     d(i - 1, j - 1) + 1 
   )
   ```
2. The use of [`std::min()` is defined to be between two values e.g. `std::min(obj1,obj2)`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/min/) whereas you are aiming use `min()` in an `R` way.

So,

```
min(c(1,2,3,4))
```

But, [C++ definition of std::min](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/min/) requires it to be written as:

```
std::min(1, std::min(2, std::min(3,4)));
```

3. If you want to be true to the `string` notion of `LevenshteinDistance`, then you need to switch how the values are entering your function away from the `NumericVector` type to any one of the following: `std::string`, `std::vector<std::string>` (see [Gallery Post: Strings with Rcpp](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/strings_with_rcpp/)), `Rcpp::StringVector` (see [Gallery Post: Working with Rcpp StringVector](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/working-with-Rcpp-StringVector/)), or `Rcpp::CharacterVector`.

The following should be sufficient:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
int LevenshteinDistance(std::string s,
                        std::string t) {

  // Number of elements
  int n = s.size();
  int m = t.size();
  Rcpp::IntegerMatrix d(n+1, m+1);
  Rcpp::Rcout << "n:" << n << ", m:" << m << std::endl;

  if (n == 0){
    return m;
  }

  if (m == 0){
    return n;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++){
    d(i, 0) = i;
  }

  // No sense to revisit the (0,0) coordinate
  for (int j = 1; j <= m; j++){
    d(0, j) = j;
  }

  for (int j = 1; j <= m; j++){

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++){

      if (s[i - 1] == t[j - 1]){

        d(i, j) = d(i - 1, j - 1);  // no operation

      } else {

        d(i, j) = std::min(d(i - 1, j) + 1,    //a deletion
                           std::min(d(i, j - 1) + 1,   //an insertion
                           d(i - 1, j - 1) + 1)); //a substitution

      } // end if

    } // end inner for

  } // end outer for

  return d(n, m);
}
```

With this function being written, we can opt to write a quick wrapper to process different dimensions of comparisons such multiple sources to a target and so on...

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::IntegerVector LevenshteinDistance_Vector(std::vector<std::string> s,
                                               std::string t){

  // Number of Sources
  unsigned int sn = s.size();

  Rcpp::IntegerVector o(sn); // populates automatically with 0.

  for(unsigned int i = 0; i < sn; i++){
    o(i) = LevenshteinDistance(s[i],t);
  }

  return o;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. Very insightful.

Comment: Would you mind elaborate on the second code ? what do you mean by `comparisons such multiple sources`?

Comment: The second part of code enables the ability to supply a vector of source words to compare to a target word e.g. `c("teste","tost")` against `"taste"` would be `LevenshteinDistance_Vector(c("teste","tost"),"taste")` giving `[1] 1 2`

Comment: I see. Thanks again.